# Navigating to Device Specific Page in Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am creating a Universal Windows App in VS 2015 that has 3 pages.  I want to navigate from Page 1 to Page 2 to Page 3.

Page 3 is a third party solution and they created the page to allow for mobile and desktop views.  That is, a XAML View (Page3.xaml) is placed inside a folder 
called DeviceFamily-Mobile and a XAML Page (Page3.xaml, (with code-behind file, Page3.xaml.cs) is placed in the same directory as the DeviceFamily-Mobile folder.

I can navigate from Page 1 to Page 2 just fine (they are not device-specific pages), and the code navigates to the OnNavigatedTo method of Page2.

However, I noticed that Frame.Naviagate returns false when I do the following from a method on Page2.xaml.cs

```
bool res = Frame.Naviagate(typeof(Page3))
```

Also, I put the cursor on Page3 and selected Go To Definition and noticed that it went to the Page3.xaml in the DeviceFamily-Mobile folder, i.e., the View,
as opposed to the Page (which has the code-behind).  I have an OnNavigatedTo method in Page3.xaml.cs but this is not being hit at all.  The XAML for both Page3.xaml files (the View and the Page) are indeed pages. That is, both have the following.  Thanks in advance.

```
<Page
 <!-- XAML CODE -->
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to navigate to another page from the OnNavigateTo method, which is not allowed.